# What is my mistake with field commuators here?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, commutator

Take a two scalar quantum fields and commute them:

$$[\phi(x),\phi(y)]$$

This must be zero if $x$ and $y$ are space-like separated. Write $y=x+a$ then expand this in a Taylor series like so:

$$[\phi(x),\phi(x)+a^\mu\partial_\mu \phi(x) + \frac{(a^\mu\partial_\mu)^2}{2!} \phi(x)+...]$$

Now if $a$ is very small this should give us simply:

$$[\phi(x),a^\mu\partial_\mu \phi(x)]$$

But doing a Lorentz transformation on $a$ should mean that if $x$ and $x+a$ are space-like they should stay space-like. But it doesn't look like the above is invariant under a Lorentz transformation of $a$ unless it is always zero. I could do a similar argument on all the terms and conclude that the first expression is always zero.

So what is my mistake?

Comment: *Why* do you think this expression should be "invariant under a Lorentz transformation of $a$"? Lorentz transformations don't act only on specific positions, they have to act on all positions. You defined $a$ as the difference of $x$ and $y$, so you must transform $x$ too if you transform $a$.

Comment: Also you need transform derivative

Comment: Well no because I'm taking the origin as $x$. So $x$ doesn't get transformed if the light cone is centered at $x$. $a$ is a vector from the origin so should stay either space-like or time-like.

Comment: Sorry i meant it should only be invariant when space-like and thus equal to zero. Not when time-like. Probably my language is all messed up here!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$[\phi(x),\partial_\mu\phi(x)] = \Big(\frac{\partial}{\partial y^\mu}[\phi(x),\phi(y)]\Big)\Big|_{y=x}$$ is not well-defined, because $[\phi(x),\phi(y)]$ is not a smooth function, but a distribution. You can define it's derivative (in terms of distributions), but you cannot evaluate it at $y=x$. As a consequence the expansion you perform is not legal.

For comparison: let's consider the Dirac's delta distribution $\delta(x)$.
Trying to make expansion around $x=0$:
$$ \delta(x) = \delta(0) + x\delta'(0) + \frac{x^2}{2}\delta''(0) + \dots$$
leads to absurd results, because neither $\delta(x)$ nor any of its derivatives can be evaluated at $0$.

Comment: Ah yes good point! The commutator has no derivative at $x$. Is there any way to fix my expression to make it legal yet still local in some sense? Or can we only write it when $|x-y|$ is non- infinitessimal. That's fascinating.

Comment: The reason is I was trying to find a way to express the fact that commuators are zero for space-like separations but as a local expression instead of a non-local expresion. But perhaps that's impossible.

Comment: Yes, so basically you'd have to check all possible paths to see if there is one that is entirely time-like. Which is why you'd use a path integral which sums over all possible paths. And the commuator just says that is zero if no time-like paths can be found. OK. So that makes sense. And that should work in curved space-times too. Thanks.